# intellij wrapping brackets around if-else

Tags: intellij-idea

Coming from a language like python, I often forget to wrap parenthesis around `if` conditions when writing Java.

Is there a parenthesis completer built into IntelliJ? If not, how do I best work around this issue? (short of manually wrapping with parenthesis myself -:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you will start typing `if` code completion will ocurs. Push enter - your carret will land inside bracket.
2. Use [surrounding blocks of code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html). You can first write boolean condition then press shortcut for `Surround With` option (on windows/linux by default it is `Ctrl + Alt + T`) and choose `if(expr)`.
   Or if you want to only surround with paranthesis, then use (Surround With) and then choose (Curly Braces).
3. You can use predefined [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) with `ifn` which will initialize if block with comparison to null. You can also configure your own template.

Also you might want to check if this option is selected in your IDE:
*Settings(Preferences) | Editor | General | Smart Keys, Surround selection on typing quote or brace*